# SSIS Row count of flat file inside for each container

Tags: ssis

I am stuck on what is ultimately a simple task.

I have a process which loads files.

The process loads these files inside a for each container.

I need to rowcount the file that is currently being processed inside the for each container and if it is over a certain number of rows then fail the file.

I have tried a control flow task but that would ultimately bypass the for each loop.

The file currently being processed is determined via a variable in the for each container, and that is the one i need to count.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a separate data flow in the For..Each to count the records and then have a Exprression and constraint linking to your main process so that you only process record counts > 0. Here's a rough layout ..
[image: Basic Control Flow / data flow]

Comment: this is what i currently have but how do i set the flat file source to the current file being processed? the source folder will have multiple files.

Comment: Are you using the For..Each loop to store the file path in a variable? You could then use this as the connection string to read the flatfile.

Comment: i wasnt, but thats an idea i hadnt considered